# Parallel Processing in docx4j

Tags: thread-safety, docx4j

Whether it is possible to process multiple paragraph simultaneously using docx4j. If possible, whether it's thread safe?

I tried to split every character into individual runs.When I process the paragraph sequentially. It's working fine. But When I tried the same process parallel. Not received the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concptually docx4j assumes one thread per WordprocessingMLPackage (ie one thread per docx).

If you want to work for a while with one thread per paragraph, that should be fine provided you aren't modifying objects higher in the hierarchy than P.